# Wald Test on two exponential samples

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, inference

Based on independent samples of data $X_i \sim$ Expon$(\lambda_1)$, $i = 1, \cdots, n,$ and $Y_j \sim$ Expon$(\lambda_2)$, $j = 1, \cdots, n$ (both samples of the sample size $n$), find the Wald test for $H_0: \lambda_1 = \lambda_2$ versus $H_1: \lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$.

$\textbf{My work}:$

Let $\theta = \lambda_1 - \lambda_2$. We can equivalently find the Wald test for $H_0: \theta = 0$ versus $H_1: \theta\neq 0.$

We know $\theta_{MLE} = \frac{1}{\bar{X}} - \frac{1}{\bar{Y}}$. Then the Wald test rejects $H_0: \theta = 0$ in favor of $H_1: \theta\neq 0$ when

$(\theta_{MLE} - 0)^2I(\theta_{MLE}) \geq x_1(1-\alpha)$, where $x_1(1-\alpha)$ is the $1 - \alpha$ quantile of the Chi-square distribution with $r$ degrees of freedom.

$\textbf{Questions:}$

1- Is my reasonning correct?

2- How can I find the fisher information $I(\theta_{MLE})$?

Thanks in advance for the help!